# Special character($) handling in linux & java

Tags: java, linux, special-characters, sign, dollar-sign

I am trying to pass a string to a java program as command line argument for some processing and it works fine, except for scenario where the String argument passed has some special characters (like $) . Doing a SOP, I find that the argument itself has been distorted with some random numbers instead of the special characters. This happens ONLY in Linux and ONLY when the argument has some special characters.

```
$ java -jar testclient.jar  String$$123
String 1 = String31733123
```

Comment: Quote it. `java -jar testclient.jar  'String$$123'`

Comment: `$$` is the process id. You need to escape it if you don't want the shell to replace it with a number. e.g. `'String$$123'`

Comment: Those are (most likely all of them) special bash variables: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Variable-Index.html - you need to "escape" them (e.g.: by surrounding your parameters with quotation marks)

Comment: But this issue happens with other special characters like !, $, & , (, ) too in Linux . Is there anything that could be done to ensure that java parses these string inputs as it is, without using escape sequences?

Answer (score 1):

> This happens ONLY in Linux and ONLY when the argument has some special characters.

That is because it is the Linux shell that is "messing" with the `$` character, not Java.

The `$` is a shell meta-character.  Specifically it introduces a shell parameter expansion.  Depending on what characters follow the `$` character, the shell will replace it / them with something else.  The modified characters are then used to for the command line arguments passed to the `java` executable.

You can find the documentation for shel parameter expansions (for the "bash" shell) here:

- https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html

Note that the same thing will happen on the Mac OSX command line and on other dialects of UNIX and Linux.

---

If you want the `$` character to be passed as-is, then it needs to be quoted.  The various ways of doing that are described here:

- https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Quoting.html#Quoting

In fact, you should probably read the entire "bash" manual ... or a tutorial.  It will save you a lot of time in the long term.

---

> Is there anything that could be done to ensure that java parses these string inputs as it is, without using escape sequences?

No.  The "damage" has already been done by the time Java sees the command line arguments.